# Animar imagenes en un ListView

Tags: android

Quiero animar (rotar) una imagen que puse en un `ListView` cuando el usuario haga clic en un item determinado de la Lista.
Como hago para obtener la imagen y aplicarle la animacion al hacer clic en la lista?

```
public class ListaConImag extends AppCompatActivity {

miAdaptador adaptador;
ArrayList<ContenidoVista> datos;
android.widget.ListView lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_con_imag);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    lista = (android.widget.ListView)findViewById(R.id.Lista_imag);
    datos = new ArrayList<ContenidoVista>();
    rellenardatos();
    adaptador = new miAdaptador(this,datos);

    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case(0):



                    break;


                case(1):
                    break;


                case(2):
                    break;


                case(3):
                    break;
            }

        }
    });


}

private void rellenardatos(){

    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("Titulo1","SubTitulo1",R.drawable.perro));
    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("Titulo2","SubTitulo2",R.drawable.perro1));
    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("Titulo3","SubTitulo3",R.drawable.perro2));
    datos.add(new ContenidoVista("Titulo4","SubTitulo4",R.drawable.persona));
  }

}
```

layout girar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="-360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="1000"
android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guarda tu animación dentro de `res/anim/`

Cargas la animación mediante la clase [AnimationUtils](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html) :

```
Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.mi_animacion);
```

y la asignas a la vista:

```
view.startAnimation(myRotation);
```

con eso haras girar tu vista al dar clic:

```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.mi_animacion);
                view.startAnimation(myRotation);
...
...
...
```

Este es un ejemplo de la animación al dar clic en las vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]